# IE8 rendering media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Im currently building a site and an issue I've come across is that ie8 is rendering all my media queries?

I'm unsure on why it's doing this and cant seem to find anything notable on Google.

I'm using html5shim to correct html5 element behaviours but I'm stumped as to why this is happening in ie8, has anybody experienced this before?

Just to show how my queries are constructed...

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 960px) and (max-width : 963px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    // Reads all of these
}
```

When I remove Modernizr my media queries then work, my html5 elements aren't rendering however now...

Comment: Does the shim include media query functionality? Most likely you need to include a specific polyfill for media queries.

Comment: The documnetation doesn't state anything about media queries. `Respond.js` is a polyfill I've used before successfully.